# Differences in capacitive loads

Tags: computer-architecture, homework, capacitive

[image]

I'm in school and I am trying to figure out a question for homework. It reads as stated:

|  | Version | Voltage | Clock Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| i. | Version 1 | 1.75V | 1.5 GHz |
|  | Version 2 | 1.2V | 2 GHz |
| ii. | Version 1 | 1.1V | 3 GHz |
|  | Version 2 | 0.8V | 4 GHz |

How much has the capacitive load varied between versions if the dynamic power has been reduced by 10%? Use table above.

I understand that Power = Capacitive Load * Voltage^2 * Frequency.

Which would translate to Capacitive Load = (Power) / Voltage^2 * Frequency.

What I don't understand is how I'm supposed to solve this without at least once source of wattage given.

Comment: I think they want a percentage. The power is 10% lower, how much lower is the capacitive load? If you need a number, you could make one up: it was 10W before and now it's 9W

Comment: @user253751 Assuming the value of power is 10W then C = 10/(1.75)^2 x (1.5 x 10^9) = 2.177 x 10^-9
Lowering the power by 10% (.9) gets me C = 10 x .9/(1.75)^2 x (1.5 x 10^9) = 1.959 x 10 ^-9
C New/C Old = 1.959 x 10^-9/ 2.177 x 10^-9 = 0.8998621957 or C New is at ~89.99% it's original capacity.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, power losses associated with driving switched capacitance are proportional to C and \$fV^2\$*k but ignore k for comparative C changes.

Voltage    Clock Rate Power
i   1.75V   1.5 GHz    4.6
ii  1.2V    2 GHz      2.9 = -37%C or **-47%C** +10%P

i   1.1V    3 GHz      3.6
ii  0.8V    4 GHz      2.56= -29%C or **-39%C** + 10%P

for a 10% power savings included

Comment: I understand how you got to -37%C & -29%C but how did you get to -47%C/10%P or -39%C/10%P